# How to create Django API without any API frameworks

Tags: python, django, api

Currently I am having a requirement for a Django project, in which I need to develop django API without using any API frameworks. So inorder to proceed I would like to know how can I do creation of API without third party frameworks.

Comment: You do understand that django is a framework and a Django API includes Django framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) to return json data in your views:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def my_view(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    return JsonResponse({'questions': questions})
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use regular function-based or class-based views as your endpoints. The difference would be is that you'll probably be sending JSON instead of rendering HTML in the response.

You can use built in decorators from Django to restrict certain access (ie. methods, permissions, etc.)

My code would look something like:

**View**

```
@require_get
@login_required
def get_user(request, userId, *args, **kwargs):
  user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=userId)
  serializer = SomeSerializerClass(user)
  return HttpResponse(serializer.jsonData(), content_type='application/json')
```

**Url**

```
url('/user/(?P<userId>[0-9]+)/$', get_user, ...)
```

Comment: The question specify that OP does not want to use any framework. The question itself is not very clear and you have explained rest framework here. How does this answer the question of OP?

Comment: In this example everything is done using Django without using a third-party API framework like RestFramework. Now, if he wanted to make API without using any frameworks including Django then he didn't make it clear in his question.

Comment: @Koralarts I have to work on Django, but I am not entitled to use any API frameworks like DRF and Tastypie

Comment: @ArpitSolanki. If you faced any problem on understanding my problem, please excuse me.. If you have any doubt you can ask?